# How do I abbreviate the mathbf command?

Tags: macros

I am finding myself needing to use the `\mathbf{}`command a lot and wish to shorten it, perhaps to `\mbf{}`. How do I do this? Creating a new command with `\newcommand{\mbf{}}{\mathbf{}}` does not seem to work.

Comment: `\newcommand\mbf{\mathbf}`

Comment: `\let\mbf\mathbf`

Comment: If you are using it a lot but only for a few symbols (like x and y), you can define \newcommabd\bx{\mathbf{x}} and use \bx everywhere for your x. This way, you can always change all of them at the same time by redefining \bx.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea because if you use a lot of abbreviations like this in your code it becomes painful for someone else to read, and maybe for you even if you come back. to your document. after some years. Understanding text quickly is important if you need to fix bugs or even edit it. There are many text editors that allow quick entry of complex commands. For example in Emacs, to type \mathbf, you can type C-c C-f C-b and the same sequence will produce \textbf if you are not in a math environment.

Comment: @gigiair Emacs with auctex to be precise ;-)

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: You might wish to make `\mbf` robust like `\mathbf`: `\DeclareRobustCommand\mbf{\mathbf}`.